# two variables has the values and that has to be compared and add in another column using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

### Variable $a Output below, Column names: VmName, RG, CurrentSKU, OS

**VmName, RG, CurrentSKU, OS**

VM1,   RG1, DS2_v2, Windows

VM2,   RG2, DS3_V3, Linux

VM3,   RG3, F4S,    Windows

VM4,   RG4, DS2_v2, Linux

### Variable $b Output below,  Column names: OldSKU, newSKU

**OldSKU, newSKU**

DS2_v2, D2as_v4

F2s,    F2sv2

DS3_V3, D2as_v4

Using Powershell I would like the output like below,

**VmName, RG, CurrentSKU, newSKU, OS,**

VM1,    RG1, DS2_v2,    D2as_v4, Windows

VM2,    RG2, DS3_V3,    D2as_v4, Linux

VM3,    RG3, F4S,       F2sv2,   Windows

VM4,    RG4, DS2_v2,    D2as_v4, Linux

quick help on this please.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$a | LeftJoin $b -on CurrentSKU -eq OldSku | Format-Table`

Comment: It works well too. Thanks @iRon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` to create a hashtable with the SKU mappings:

```
# Recreate data from question
$a = @'
"VmName","RG","CurrentSKU","OS"
"VM1","RG1","DS2_v2","Windows"
"VM2","RG2","DS3_V3","Linux"
"VM3","RG3","F4S","Windows"
"VM4","RG4","DS2_v2","Linux"
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv
$b = @'
"OldSKU","newSKU"
"DS2_v2","D2as_v4"
"F2s","F2sv2"
"DS3_V3","D2as_v4"
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# Create hashtable from second dataset
$skuTable = $b |Group-Object OldSKU -AsHashTable
```

Then use `Select-Object` to attach a new `newSKU` property with the mapped value:

```
$c = $a |Select-Object VmName,RG,CurrentSKU,@{Name='NewSKU';E={$skuTable[$_.CurrentSKU].newSKU}},OS
```

`$c` now contains a new list of objects like the one you describe:

```
PS ~> $c |Format-Table

VmName RG  CurrentSKU NewSKU  OS
------ --  ---------- ------  --
VM1    RG1 DS2_v2     D2as_v4 Windows
VM2    RG2 DS3_V3     D2as_v4 Linux
VM3    RG3 F4S                Windows
VM4    RG4 DS2_v2     D2as_v4 Linux
```

Comment: Looks like this is not helping and got the below error,


$Skutable = $b | Group-Object olderGenSKU -AsHashTable

Group-Object: The objects grouped by this property cannot be expanded because there is a key duplication. Provide a valid value for tl At line:1 char:18

+ $Skutable = $b | Group-Object OlderGenSKU -AsHashTable
+
+ CategoryInfo
: InvalidArgument: (:) [Group-Object], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : The objects grouped by this property cannot be expanded because there is a key duplication. Provide a va en try again

Comment: @Venkatesh Perhaps your data doesn't look quite the way you've described it? I've updated my answer to show how I generated the test data

Comment: @Venkatesh The error means that your `$b` array has at least 2 objects with the same `oldSKU` value

Comment: I will give a try out with the provided updated script.

Comment: @Venkatesh I haven't updated the script - you will still have the same error if your input data contains duplicates

Comment: Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I create tables $a and $b to test code

```
$a = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   VmName = 'VM1'
   RG = 'RG1'
   CurrentSKU = 'DS2_v2'
   OS = 'Windows'
}
$a.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   VmName = 'VM2'
   RG = 'RG2'
   CurrentSKU = 'DS3_v3'
   OS = 'Linux'
}
$a.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   VmName = 'VM3'
   RG = 'RG3'
   CurrentSKU = 'F4S'
   OS = 'Windows'
}
$a.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   VmName = 'VM4'
   RG = 'RG4'
   CurrentSKU = 'DS2_v2'
   OS = 'Linux'
}
$a.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$b = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   OldSKU = 'DS2_v2'
   newSKU = 'D2as_v4'
}
$b.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   OldSKU = 'F4s'
   newSKU = 'F2sv2'
}
$b.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   OldSKU = 'DS3_v3'
   newSKU = 'D2as_v4'
}
$b.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$a
$b

foreach($row in $a)
{
$row | format-list
   $SKU = $b | Where-Object { $_.OldSKU -eq $row.CurrentSKU }
$SKU
   $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName newSKU -NotePropertyValue $SKU.newSKU
}

$a | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

as (probably less efficient) alternative:

```
 $a | foreach-object {
     $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name newSKU -Value $(
          if ($_.CurrentSKU -in $b.oldsku){
              $b[$b.oldsku.IndexOf($_.CurrentSKU)].newSKU
          }
     )
 }
```

results in:

```
 PS> $a | Format-Table
     
     
     VmName RG  CurrentSKU OS      newSKU
     ------ --  ---------- --      ------
     VM1    RG1 DS2_v2     Windows D2as_v4
     VM2    RG2 DS3_V3     Linux   D2as_v4
     VM3    RG3 F4S        Windows
     vM4    RG4 DS2_v2     Linux   D2as_v4
```

Note well: you still need $b only having unique `oldSKU` values